# JSPDF text overlapping and dynamic page generation

Tags: javascript, angular, jspdf

I'm using JSPDF for my webapp but I'm stuck with two issues:

First: Text is overlapping like this:

[image]

Second: I add pages dynamically (I'm getting the text from an endpoint) but the content does not continues in the new pages (they are blank or with just a chunk of text).

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
    const doc = new jsPDF('portrait', 'mm', 'letter');

    let pageWidth = 215.9;
    let pageHeight = 279.4;
    let pageMargin = 7;

    pageWidth -= pageMargin * 2;
    pageHeight -= pageMargin * 2;

    let y = 60;
    let count:number = 0;

    //Here I iterate over the object returned from the API, I have a subtitle and a set of recommendations

    Object.keys(recommendations).forEach((subtitle) => {
      doc.setFont('value-sans-medium-pro');
      doc.setFontSize(18);
      doc.setTextColor(0, 0, 0);
      let size = 18;
      count += 22.5;
      let offsetTitle = y + count;
      doc.text('' + subtitle, 15.875, offsetTitle);

      recommendations[subtitle].forEach((description, index) => {
        doc.setFont('value-sans-regular-pro');
        doc.setFontSize(12);
        doc.setTextColor(0, 0, 0);
        let lines = doc.splitTextToSize(description, 185);
        let size = 12;
        count += 10;

        let offset = y + count;

        doc.text(lines, 15.875, offset)

        // offset += (lines.length + 63.5) * size / 50
      });

      if ( y + count > pageHeight ) {
        doc.addPage();
        y = 0;
        console.log('Adding page');
      }
```

I have tried to follow the example in the documentation without success.

The outcome is like this: (sorry for the blurred text)

[image]

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I am using JSpdf library.For me as well text is overlapping.How to set JSON data in multiple lines.Please help me on this.I am new to react